# What does this variable notation mean ? a[++b]=$c

Tags: bash, variables

I have seen this notation in bash:

```
 a=${b[c--]}
```

or also

```
 a[++b]=$c
```

or the other way around:

```
 a[b++]=$c
```

but if I execute it on the command line nothing happens.

```
 OSX@26:~ $ a[++b]=2
 OSX@27:~ $ echo ${a[++b]}

 OSX@28:~ $
```

What is the use of this notation ?

Edit:

I am asking about this notation. As I have seen it it is a variable, because of the $ in front. But ++ does remind me of increment, so I am confused. Is this some sort of variable increment ?

Comment: What are you asking about, array notation or pre-/postfix increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c--` is an arithmetic expression, it means "return the value of `c` and then decrement it by 1". `${b[n]}` denotes the `n`-th element of the array `b` (where the first element has index 0). Expressions inside the square brackets are interpreted as arithmetic (with some exceptions like `*`, `@`, `'1'` etc.) Let's try it:

```
b=(x y z)
c=2
a=${b[c--]}
echo $a $c  # Outputs: z 1
```

so `c--` returns 2, but sets `c` to 1. `b[2]`, i.e. `z`, is then assigned to `a`.

`++c` is similar to `c--`, but it adds 1 to `c` *before* returning its value.

Comment: @azbc Please note not seeing anything when doing `echo ${a[++b]}` on the command line is related to the fact that `++b` is an array index that has not yet been assigned.